# Geometric correction in ArcMap makes no changes in output image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, orthorectification, image-analysis

I am using the [Geometric function](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/geometric-function.htm) in ArcMap (Windows -- İmage Analysis). I only used the DEM for the correction. But the output looks exactly the same as input.

İt is a very hilly region, and I am sure there are terrain distortions but why there are no changes for the output?

My ınput image is 1 m resolution, the DEM is 30 m.

Comment: Yes. I put constant Z =1 and DEM (30 m), all other settings are 0.

Comment: Another question, after using DEM to do the orthorectification with this function, will I also get Z value for each pixel? Will the Z values from DEM be transferred to the output image?